# UUID send to client with str(value) but ib server when receive back badly formed hexadecimal string

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, uuid

I ma using in SQLAlchemy uuid4 for one column and I got value like `16d11d6abdaf4fe9905a56e0be8d15d1`
I need to send this id to client using json format and in future to receive from client id and make query over database.
I am sending like

```
result = {'id': str(id)}
#this is from Tornado handler
self.write(simplejson.dumps(result))
```

when I send from user json with id which I received, on server I extract like

```
data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
id = data.get('id', None)
#also tornado handler when I receive id from client
#I also have tried like uuid.UUID(bytes=id.bytes) but also get error
```

I always get error like badly formed hexadecimal string. How to send to client and from client to server uuid in json ?

Answer (score 0):

The frist:

```
result = {'id': str(id)}
#If the given chunk is a dictionary, we write it as JSON and set
#the Content-Type of the response to be application/json.
self.write(result)
```

Secend:

```
#Returns the value of the argument with the given name
id = self.get_argument("id")
```

I'm sorry,My English is poor